# An algorithm to generate a game map from individual images

Tags: algorithm

I am designing a game to be played in the browser.

Game is a space theme and I need to generate a map of the "Galaxy".

The basic idea of the map is here:

[game map http://www.oglehq.com/map.png](http://www.oglehq.com/map.png)

The map is a grid, with each grid sector can contain a planet/system and each of these has links to a number of adjacent grids.

To generate the maps I figured that I would have a collection of images representing the grid elements. So in the case of the sample above, each of the squares is a separate graphic.

To create a new map I would "weave" the images together. 
The map element images would have the planets and their links already on them, and I, therefore, need to stitch the map together in such a way that each image is positioned with its appropriate counterparts => so the image in the bottom corner must have images to the left and diagonal left that link up with it correctly.

How would you go about creating the code to know where to place the images? 
Is there a better way than using images?

At the moment performance and/or load should not be a consideration (if I need to generate maps to have preconfigured rather than do it in real-time, I don't mind).

If it makes a difference I will be using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and backed by a Ruby on Rails app.

Comment: did you ever finish this game? Can we find it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two very nice browser-based vector / javascript-manipulable graphics packages which, together, are virtually universal: SVG and VML.  They generally produce high-quality vector-based images with low bandwidth.

[SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) is supported by firefox, opera, safari, and chrome - technically only part of the specification is supported, but for practical purposes you should be able to do what you need.  w3schools has [a good reference for learning/using svg](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_examples.asp).

[VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) is Microsoft's answer to SVG, and (surprise) is natively supported by IE, although SVG is not.  Msdn has the best [reference for vml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263898(VS.85).aspx).

Although it's more work, you could write two similar/somewhat integrated code bases for these two technologies.  The real benefit is that users won't have to install anything to play your game online - it'll just work, for 99.9% of all users.

By the way, you say that you're asking for an algorithm, and I'm offering technologies (if that's the right term for SVG/VML).  If you could clarify the input/output specification and perhaps what part presents the challenge (e.g. which naive implementation won't work, and why), that would clarify the question and maybe provide more focused answers.

**Addendum** [The canvas tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_%28HTML_element%29) is becoming more widely supported, with the notable exception of IE.  This might be a cleaner way to embed graphic elements in html.

Useful canvas stuff: [Opera's canvas tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/) | [Mozilla's canvas tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) | [canvas-in-IE partial implementation](http://me.eae.net/archive/2005/12/29/canvas-in-ie/)

Comment: Pedantry: VML was a proposed standard (by Microsoft) turned into SVG by the W3C because it was, in its proposed form, a bit silly. Also, w3schools is a terrible reference, tho I can admittedly not think of any good ones for SVG off the top of my head, apart from the spec (at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG).

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. If each box can only link to its 8 neighbours, then you only have 2^8 = 256 tile types. Fewer if you limit the number of possible links from any one tile.

You can encode which links are present in an image with an 8 char filename:

```
11000010.jpeg
```

Or save some bytes and convert that to decimal or hex

```
196.jpg
```

Then the code. There's lots of ways you could choose to represent the map internally. One way is to have an object for each planet. A planet object knows its own position in the grid, and the positions of its linked planets. Hence it has enough information to choose the appropriate file.

Or have a 2D array. To work out which image to show for each array item, look at the 8 neighbouring array items. If you do this, you can avoid coding for boundaries by making the array two bigger in both axes, and having an empty 'border' around the edges. This saves you checking whether a neighbouring array item is off the array.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to represent your map.

One way is to represent it is a grid of squares, where each square can have a planet/system in it or not. You can then specify that if there is a neighbor one square away in any of the eight directions (NW, N, NE, W, E, SW, S, SE) then there is a connection to that neighbor. Note however in your sample map the center system is not connected to the system north/east of it, so perhaps this is not the representation you want. But it can be used to build the other representation

The second way is to represent each square as having eight bits, defining whether or not there is a connection to a neighbor along each of the same eight directions. Presumably if there is even one connection, then the square has a system inside it, otherwise if there are no connections it is blank.

So in your example 3x3 grid, the data would be:

```
 Tile   Connections
        nw  n ne  w  e sw  s se
 nw      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 n       0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
 ne      0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
 w       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 center  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1
 e       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 se      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 s       0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
 sw      1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

You could represent these connections as an array of eight boolean values, or much more compactly as an eight bit integer.

Its then easy to use the eight boolean values (or the eight bit integer) to form the filename of the bitmap to load for that grid square. For example, your center tile using this scheme could be called "Bitmap01000011.png" (just using the boolean values), or alternatively "Bitmap43.png" (using the hexidecimal value of the eight bit integer representing that binary pattern for a shorter filename).

Since you have 256 possible combinations, you will need 256 bitmaps.

You could also reduce the data to four booleans/bits per tile, since a "north" connection for instance implies that the tile to the north has a "south" connection, but that makes selecting the bitmaps a bit harder, but you can work it out if you want.

Alternatively you could layer between zero (empty) and nine (fully connected + system circle) bitmaps together in each square. You would just need to use transparent .png's so that you could combine them together. The downside is that the browser might be slow to draw each square (especially the fully connected ones). The advantage would be less data for you to create, and less data to load from your website.

You would represent the map itself as a table, and add your bitmaps as image links to each cell as needed.

The pseudo-code to map would be:

```
draw_map(connection_map):
    For each grid_square in connection_map
        connection_data = connection_map[grid_square]
        filenames = bitmap_filenames_from(connection_data)
        insert_image_references_into_table(grid_square,filenames)

# For each square having one of 256 bitmaps:
bitmap_filenames_from(connection_data):
    filename="Bitmap"
    for each bit in connection_data:
      filename += bit ? "1" : 0
    return [filename,]

# For each square having zero through nine bitmaps:
bitmap_filename_from(connection_data):
    # Special case - square is empty
    if 1 not in connection_data:
        return []
    filenames=[]
    for i in 0..7:
        if connection_data[i]:
            filenames.append("Bitmap"+i)
    filenames.append("BitmapSystem");
    return filenames
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a graphics library to draw the map. If you do you won't have the above problem and you will end up with much cleaner/simpler code. Some options are SVG, Canvas, and flash/flex.

Comment: Sure, but I will still have the same essential problem, in terms of generating a network of nodes and links to those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just render the links in game, and have the cell graphics only provide a background. This gives you more flexibility, allows you to more easily increase the number of ways cells can link to each other, and generally more scalable.

Otherwise you will need to account for every possible way a cell might be linked, and this is rather a lot even if you take into account rotational and mirror symmetries.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, and you could also just have a small number of tile png files with transparency on them, and overlap these using css-positioned div's to form a picture similar to your example, if that suffices.

Last time I checked, older versions of IE did not have great support for transparency in image files, though.  Can anyone edit this to provide better info on transparency support?

Comment: IE7 and up have workable support for good PNG transparency, and earlier versions support 1-bit transparency.

Answer (score -1):

As long as links have a maximum length that's not too long, then you don't have too many different possible images for each cell. You need to come up with an ordering on the kinds of image cells. For example, an integer where each bit indicates the presense or absence of an image component.

```
Bit 0 : Has planet
Bit 1 : Has line from planet going north
Bit 2 : Has line from planet going northwest
...
Bit 8 : Has line from planet going northeast
```

Ok, now create 512 images. Many languages have libraries that let you edit and write images to disk. If you like Ruby, try this: http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-gd

I don't know how you plan to store your data structure describing the graph of planets and links. An [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) might make it easy to generate the map, although it's not the smallest representation by far. Then it's pretty straightforward to spit out html like (for a 2x2 grid):

```
<table border="0" cellspace="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="cell_X.gif"></td>
<td><img src="cell_X.gif"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="cell_X.gif"></td>
<td><img src="cell_X.gif"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Of course, replace each X with the appropriate number corresponding to the combination of bits describing the appearance of the cell. If you're using an adjacency matrix, putting the bits together is pretty simple--just look at the cells around the "current" cell.

Comment: @Williham: come on, table layout is not automatically bad. Some people treat it like it's a goto or something. Table layouts are efficient and clear for certain applications, especially when the number of rows/columns is small. You're welcome to your opinions, but it's not worth a downvote.